# Date Range Search in Datatables using PHP Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am using Date Range Search in Data tables using PHP Ajax. It provide start / end date pick function in format YYYY-MM-DD. I took this code from [webslesson.info](http://www.webslesson.info/2017/06/date-range-search-in-datatables-using-php-ajax.html)

I want to have format like "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS". How can I modify it.

Comment: Did you try to manipulate the date picker?

Comment: you can't make this format to "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" because this is a datepicker not time picker you can make this like "YYYY-MM-DD"

Comment: You have to use datetimepicker for the format you want...

Comment: When your question contains code, you should include the code in the question, not link it. Please do that.

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to change date range format of `datepicker`
here is the working code

```
$('.input-daterange').datepicker({
  format: "YYYY-MM-DD"
 });
```

Comment: @kumar,
using that code it shows date like "YYYY-November-Wednesday"

Comment: Then what you want basically can you please explain in details

Comment: Ok. I have SYSLOG tables that have DATE TIME column as well which records time in "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" format. Therefore I need to add search option which have such format so search can be made. I used same code from internet (link is given in first post) but it provide date picker in YYYY-MM-DD only, and dueto this search does not work